# Intuitive proof of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} k^{k-1} (n-k)^{n-k} = n^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics, binomial-theorem

Is there an intuitive way, though I am not sure how to find a conceptual proof either, to establish the following identity:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} k^{k-1} (n-k)^{n-k} = n^n$$
for all natural numbers.

I am thinking about binomial formula
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk x^{n-k}y^k=(x+y)^n$$
but I'm not sure how to use it.

I find this problem tantalizing because it looks as if there should be some sort of intuitive way so that is why I share it here. I am looking for an answer like [my question before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/876922/164058) if possible. Can you find one?

Comment: Does $j$ in the first formula means $k$?

Comment: You tried induction?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76182/how-to-prove-a-combinatorics-identity)

Answer (score 12):

This is a nice variant of *Abel's identity* which is sometimes considered as *deep* generalisation of the binomial theorem. This formulation can be found e.g. in the classic *[Advanced Combinatorics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9027703809)* by Louis Comtet in section 3.1. The identity is stated there in the form
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x(x-kz)^{k-1}(y+kz)^{n-k}=(x+y)^{n}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
valid for all x,y,z in a commutative ring. If we put $z=0$ we recover the binomial identity.

In a comment to OPs question @ArtW refers to a *[paper](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v17i1n24)* by Wengchang Chu which presents an instructive, elementary proof which is the basis of this answer.

**Proof of Abel's identity**

In fact it is more convenient to prove a generalised version of OPs claim. In a second step we then show that OPs formula is a particular variant of the general identity. We prove the identity (1) in the special case $z=-1$ which is appropriate for us and show:

> The following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x(x+k)^{k-1}(y-k)^{n-k}=(x+y)^n\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n&\binom{n}{k}x(x+k)^{k-1}(y-k)^{n-k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x(x+k)^{k-1}((x+y)-(x+k))^{n-k}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x(x+k)^{k-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{j}(-1)^j(x+k)^j(x+y)^{n-k-j}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x(x+k)^{k-1}\sum_{j=k}^{n}\binom{n-k}{j-k}(-1)^{j-k}(x+k)^{j-k}(x+y)^{n-j}\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=k}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x(x+y)^{n-j}\binom{n-k}{j-k}(-1)^{j-k}(x+k)^{j-1}\tag{6}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}x(x+y)^{n-j}\sum_{k=0}^{j}\binom{j}{k}(-1)^{j-k}(x+k)^{j-1}\tag{7}\\
> &=(x+y)^n\tag{8}
> \end{align*}
>   and  (2) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (3) we replace $y-k$ with $(x+y)-(x+k)$ without changing anything, since we are adding zero only.
- In (4) we apply the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem)* to $$((x+y)-(x+k))^{n-k}$$
- In (5) we shift the index $j$ by $k$  in the inner sum
- In (6) we collect the factors of $(x+k)$ and exchange inner and outer sum by respecting
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=k}^n a_{j,k}=\sum_{0\leq k\leq j\leq n} a_{j,k}=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^ja_{j,k}
  \end{align*}
- In    (7) we use the identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{j-k}=\binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{k}
  \end{align*}
- In (8)  we observe that the inner sum is a polynomial in $k$ of degree $j-1$. We also note that the *[difference operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)* $\Delta$
  \begin{align*}
  \Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)
  \end{align*}
  when applied to a polynomial reduces the degree by one. Since the inner sum of (8) is the Delta operator applied $j$ times to the polynomial $(x+k)^{j-1}$ (see the referred Wiki page for this) and the degree of the polynomial is less than $j$, it *vanishes* whenever $j>0$ .
  \begin{align*}
  \Delta^{j}(x+k)^{j-1}=\sum_{k=0}^j\binom{j}{k}(-1)^{j-k}(x+k)^{j-1}=0\qquad\qquad j>0
  \end{align*}
  So, we have only to consider $j=0$ in (7) resulting in $(x+y)^n$.

> **Deriving OPs formula**
>
> We can write Abel's identity (2) in case $x\ne 0$ in the form
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}(x+k)^{k-1}(y-k)^{n-k}=\frac{(x+y)^n-y^n}{x}
> \end{align*}
>
> Letting $x\rightarrow 0$ we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}k^{k-1}(y-k)^{n-k}=ny^{n-1}
> \end{align*}
>
> Finally putting $y=n$ we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}k^{k-1}(n-k)^{n-k}=n^n
> \end{align*}
>   and OPs claim follows.

**Note:** Abel's identity comes in many different shapes. A nice collection can be found in *[this paper](http://www.ebyte.it/library/educards/math/2014_MATH_Sykora_AbelCorollaries.pdf)* by Stanislav Sykora. OPs identity is listed as (13) in the paper. Amusingly and indicating the beauty of the formula he states in a footnote that precisely *this* identity was the reason for his recherche. He also presents a copy of the original proof by Abel from 1826.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**. This may be seen as a particular case of Abel-Hurwitz binomial identity, see a probabilistic explanation  [here](http://www.theoremoftheday.org/Statistics/AbelHurwitz/TotDAbelHurwitz.pdf). Combinatorial proofs are given in references $[8,11,19,21]$ of this [paper](http://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/500.pdf). See also this [paper](http://www.ebyte.it/library/educards/math/2014_MATH_Sykora_AbelCorollaries.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm just a 10-grader, couldn't understand those papers

Comment: [Here](http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_17/PDF/v17i1n24.pdf) is another, more accessible short proof.

Answer (score 6):

There is a combinatorial proof of this as well. $n^n=n\cdot n\cdot n^{n-2}$ counts the number of doubly rooted labeled trees on the set $N:=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. We describe a bijection which takes a doubly rooted tree $(T,u,v)$ to a pair $\Big((T_1,r),(T_2,s,t)\Big)$, where

- $(T_1,r)$ is a rooted tree on a nonempty subset $K$ of $N$,
- $(T_2,s,t)$ is a doubly rooted tree on $N\setminus K$. The only exception is when $N\setminus K$ is empty, in which case $T_2$ is the empty tree and has no roots.

This bijection proves the desired equality, since

- $k:=|K|$ can be any number between $1$ and $n$,
- there are $\binom{n}k$ ways to choose $K$,
- there are $k^{k-1}$ to choose a labeled rooted tree on $K$,
- there are $(n-k)^{n-k}$ ways to choose a labeled doubly rooted tree on $N\setminus K$. This works even when $N\setminus K$ is empty, as $0^0=1$, and there is one empty tree.

Here is bijection. Given the doubly rooted tree $(T,u,v)$, there are two cases.

1. If $u=v$, then $K=N$, $T_1=T$, $r=u=v$, and $T_2$ is empty.
2. Otherwise, let $w$ be the vertex adjacent to $u$ on the path from $u$ to $v$ in $T$. If you remove the edge $(u,w)$, then $T$ splits into two trees $T_1$ and $T_2$, where $u\in T_1$ and $w,v\in T_2$. We let $u$ be the root of $T_1$, and let $v$ and $w$ be the roots of $T_2$.

Comment: Worth adding how you get the inverse of the bijection - given  $(T_1,r)$ and $(T_2,s,t)$ labeled disjointly, we get $T$ by adding an edge between $s$ and $r,$  and then we get $(T,r,t)$ When $T_2$ is empty, we get $(T_1,r,r).$

Answer (score 3):

Going to reply to your request for an *intuitive way*, let me first summarize what has been already presented in the 
answers and in the references given here and in the connected post.
I will then mention the results provided in a futher work [3], which goes forward in generalizing the binomial theorem,
and better enlighten what is going on this very interesting scene.

So the identity in your post is a particular case of the most general form of Abel Identity, as in Markus' answer, in reference [1] and in other works, which may be written as
$$
\tag{1} z^{\,n}  = a\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n \\ 
 k \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left( {a - kb} \right)^{\,k - 1} \left( {z - a + kb} \right)^{\,n - k} }
$$
En passant note that the "Abel Series"
$$ f(z) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\frac{{f^{\left( k \right)} \left( {k\,t} \right)}}{{k!}}z\left( {z - k\,t} \right)^{\,k - 1} } $$
would give for $z^n$ the identity above with $a=z$.

Now in [2] the Abel's Identity is rewritten as:
$$
\tag{2.a} \frac{{z^{\,n} }}{{n!}} = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\frac{a}{{a - bk}}\frac{{\left( {a - bk} \right)^{\,k} }}{{k!}}} \frac{{\left( {z - \left( {a - bk} \right)} \right)^{\,n - k} }}{{\left( {n - k} \right)!}}
$$
and parallaled with the Hagen-Rothe identity
$$
\tag{2.b} \left( \begin{array}{c}
 z \\ 
 n \\ 
 \end{array} \right) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\frac{a}{{a - bk}}\left( \begin{array}{c}
 a - bk \\ 
 k \\ 
 \end{array} \right)} \left( \begin{array}{c}
 z - \left( {a - bk} \right) \\ 
 n - k \\ 
 \end{array} \right)
$$
that is:
$$
\tag{2.c} \frac{{z^{\,\underline {\,n\,} } }}{{n!}} = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\frac{a}{{a - bk}}\frac{{\left( {a - bk} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } }}{{k!}}} \frac{{\left( {z - \left( {a - bk} \right)} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n - k\,} } }}{{\left( {n - k} \right)!}}
$$
and it can be easily proved that it holds for the rising factorial as well
$$
\tag{2.d} \frac{{z^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } }}{{n!}} = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\frac{a}{{a - bk}}\frac{{\left( {a - bk} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}{{k!}}} \frac{{\left( {z - \left( {a - bk} \right)} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n - k\,} } }}{{\left( {n - k} \right)!}}
$$

In paper [3] then the authors present and analyze how Gould has further extended the representation to
$$
\tag{3} z^{\,n}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n \\ 
 k \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\;c(k)\left( {z - \beta _{\,k} } \right)^{\,n - k} \,} 
$$
where $\beta _{\,k} $,  with $\beta _{\,0}  \ne 0$ is a general sequence (even complex)
and the coefficients $c(k)$, with $c(0)=1$, are uniquely determined
by a recurrence relation that is easily determined by imposing that it should be valid also for $z=0$.
Note that for integer $\beta _{\,k} $, the $c(k)$ are also integers (and symmetric polynomials in $\beta _{\,k} $).
Taking the linear sequence $\beta _{\,k}  = a - bk$ then gives Abel's identity.

Finally we come to see that Gould's Identity is just the representation of the polynomial $z^n$
in the basis given by the polynomials ${\left( {z - \beta _{\,k} } \right)^{\,n - k} }$

---

References
[1]   "An Abel's Identity and its Corollaries" - Stanislav Sykora - ExtraByte, Castano Primo (MI), Italy Ed. June 2014
 http://ebyte.it/library/educart/math/2014_MATH_Sykora_AbelCorollaries.pdf
[2]   "Elementary Proofs for Convolution Identities of Abel and Hagen–Rothe" - Wenchang Chu - The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics - Vol.17 -2010 http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_17/PDF/v17i1n24.pdf
[3]   "On Abel-Gontscharoff-Gould’s Polynomials" - T. X. He, L. C. Hsu, P. J. S. Shiue - Illinois Wesleyan University http://sun.iwu.edu/~the/AGGpoly.pdf

Comment: @G Cab Thank you for this information! (+1)

Comment: @OlivierOloa glad that you appreciated. The area of conversion between polynomial basis is much interesting in fact, and I would like that this post remains alive to collect contributions from the community, or that a dedicated area be open (but I do not have experience on how to propose this).

Answer (score 1):

Difference operator:$\Delta f(k)=f(k+1)-f(k)$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\Delta f(k)=f(n+1)-f(0),
$$
and we let
$$
f(k)=\binom{x}k^p(k!)^py^{-kp},
$$
Apply to above equation, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta f(k)
&=\binom{x}{k+1}^p(k+1)!^py^{-kp-p}-\binom{x}k^p(k!)^py^{-kp}\\
&=\binom xk^p(k!)^py^{-p(k+1)}[(x-k)^p-y^p]\\
\end{aligned}
$$
By using above sum equation,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{k=0}^n\binom xk^p(k!)^py^{-p(k+1)}[(x-k)^p-y^p]\\
=&\binom x{n+1}^p(n+1)!^py^{-pn-p}-1,
\end{aligned}
$$
Both sides are multiplied together $y^{pn+p}$, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{k=0}^n\binom xk^p(k!)^py^{p(n-k)}[(x-k)^p-y^p]\\
=&\binom x{n+1}^p(n+1)!^p-y^{p(n+1)},
\end{aligned}
$$
let $p=1,x=n-1,y=n$, and we obtain
$$
\sum_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n-1}\binom{n-1}kn^{n-1-k}(k+1)!=n^n.
$$