# Simplifying a sum of binomial coefficients multiplied by power of choice number

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that
> $$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(k+1)^{k-1}(n+1-k)^{n-k} = (n+2)^n$$

Trying to generalize a combinatorial problem, my collegue have obtained the LHS with some numerical evidences which indicates the equation may holds.
I have tried to prove it elementarily but failed.

What I have succeeded is to prove it using exponential generating function with Lambert omega function.

The exponential generating function of the LHS is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} (k+1)^{k-1} (n+1-k)^{n-k}
$$
which can be arranged
$$
\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(k+1)^k}{(k+1)!}x^k \right) \left( \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{(l+1)^l}{l!} x^l \right)
$$
Let $L(x) = -W_0(-x)$ where $W_0$ is the principal branch of the Lambert $W$ function.
Then the series expression $L(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{n-1}}{n!} x^n$ and the differential equation $xL'(x) = \frac{L(x)}{1-L(x)}$ and hence the series expression $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^n}{n!} x^n = \frac{L(x)}{1-L(x)}$ holds.
These observations at hands, the exponential generating function of the LHS can be written as
$$
\left(L(x)/x \right) \left(\frac{ L(x)}{x(1-L(x))} \right) = \frac{L(x)^2}{x^2(1-L(x))}
$$

On the otherhand the exponential generationg function of the RHS is $\left( L(x)/x \right)'$.
But then
$$
 \left(\frac{L(x)}{x}\right)' = \frac{xL'(x)-L(x)}{x^2} = \frac{L(x)^2}{x^2(1-L(x))}
$$
which completes the proof.

However, I thing there would be a beautiful combinatorial argument which proves the identity. Is there anyone who can help to find such a proof?

Comment: You know, when I actually saw the question first, I almost commented that “hey, don’t go for the overkill. Just trust the binomial theorem”. Then I scrolled up to see the question again, and…oof.

Comment: @insipidintegrator haha exactly. I tried manipulating it with basic binomial theorem, ended up with $$2^nS=(n+2)^{n}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(n+1-k)^{-k}(k+1)^{k-n}$$ which is equally daunting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** This is a  variant of *Abel's identity* which is sometimes considered as *deep* generalisation of the binomial theorem. This formulation can be found e.g. in the classic *[Advanced Combinatorics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9027703809)* by Louis Comtet in section 3.1. The identity is stated there in the form
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x(x-kz)^{k-1}(y+kz)^{n-k}=(x+y)^{n}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
valid for all x,y,z in a commutative ring. If we put $z=0$ we recover the binomial identity.

> Using the substitution $x\to 1, y\to n+1, z\to -1$ we obtain OPs identity
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(k+1)^{k-1}(n+1-k)^{n-k} = (n+2)^n}
> \end{align*}

- An elementary algebraic proof is given *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823244/intuitive-proof-of-sum-k-1n-binomnk-kk-1-n-kn-k-nn/1852052#1852052)*.
- A combinatorial proof based upon *[Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula)*
  $n^{n-2}$, the number of trees with $n$ labeled vertices, is also provided there.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here are the details of the combinatorial proof referenced in [epi163sqrt's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4473859).

Let $[n]$ denote $\{1,\dots,n\}$, for any $n\in \Bbb N$.

By Cayley's formula, $(n+2)^{n}$ is the number of labeled trees on the set $[n]\cup \{x,y\}$, where $x$ and $y$ are two special symbols which are not in $[n]$.

Alternatively, to specify a tree on $[n]\cup\{x,y\}$, you can

- choose a number $k\in \{0,1,\dots,n\}$.
- choose a subset $K$ of $[n]$ with $k$ elements, in $\binom{n}k$ ways.
- choose a labeled tree on $K\cup \{x\}$, in $(k+1)^{k-1}$ ways.
- choose a labeled, *rooted* tree on $([n]\setminus K)\cup \{y\}$, in $(n-k+1)^{n-k}$ ways,
- finally, unite these two trees by joining $x$ to the root of the second tree with an edge.

This operation defines a tree on the entire set $[n]\cup \{x,y\}$. Furthermore, it is reversible. Given a tree on $[n]\cup \{x,y\}$, consider the path joining $x$ to to $y$, and deleted the edge of this path with is incident to $x$. What remains are two disjoint trees, where one tree has the $x$ vertex and the other has the $y$ vertex. Furthermore, the vertex of the second tree which was originally adjacent to $x$ is special, so is singled out as the root.

Since the numbered of ways to complete the bulleted steps is $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk(k+1)^{k-1}(n-k+1)^{n-k}$, the equality is proved.